# using a list<> as converterparameter in a gridview

Tags: wpf, gridview, binding, converters

I want to be able to convert an integer to a string using a lookup table (list) in my code.
Both the integer and the list is passed on from a COM and bound to observables in my code.

```
<ListView Name="IdList" MaxWidth="310" Height="190" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TypeItem.Ids}">'

<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShipType, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ShipTypeConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype}}"/>`
```

I have tried using multibinding, but only got DependencyProperty.UnsetValue for the list value

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
  <GridViewColumnHeader Content="ShipType"/>
  <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding >
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ShipTypeMultiConverter}">
      <Binding Path="ShipType"/>
      <Binding Path="ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
</GridViewColumn>

[ValueConversion(typeof(byte), typeof(string))]
public class ShipTypeMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            byte state = (byte)values[0];
            List<StaticId> list = (List<StaticId>)values[1];
            return state.ToString();
        }

        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Also tried using templates, but I think I got  lost in the XAML :).

vm is a reference  to my ViewModel
the TypeItem.Ids is defined as List, where Static is an observable class containing amongst other stuff the ShipType value

Does anybody have any suggestions how to solve this?`enter code here`

Comment: I you don't convert does it work (but display an integer)? Post your converter.

Comment: Yes the numeric value is shown in the column

Comment: Is the converter called?  If so catch the exception an view the message.  catch (Exception Ex)

Comment: I think you problem is <Binding Path="ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype"/>  I doubt ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype is a property of TypeItem.Ids  You are going to need to use Source= type syntax.

Comment: "ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype" is of type SerializableDictionary<uint, string>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the solution was:

1. Adding a source to my resource dictionary

   ```
   <CollectionViewSource
       x:Key="ShipTypeSource"
       Source="{Binding ConfigStaticItem.alternatives_shiptype}"
       />
   ```
2. Using a standard binding with the static resource as converter parameter

   ```
   <GridViewColumn
       Width="Auto"
       Header="Ship Type"
       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShipType, Converter={StaticResource ShipTypeConverter},
       ConverterParameter={StaticResource ShipTypeSource}}"
       />
   ```
3. And using a singlevalue converter

   ```
   [ValueConversion(typeof(byte), typeof(string))]
   public class ShipTypeConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           try
           {
               Alternatives ShipTypes = (Alternatives)((parameter as CollectionViewSource).Source);
               byte Type = (byte)value;
               foreach (var key in ShipTypes)
               {
                   if ((uint)Type == key.Key)
                   {
                       return key.Value;
                   }
               }
               return ""; // Ship type is undefined
           }

           catch
           {
               return "";
           }
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```